# How to correctly benchmark I/O performance in CSharp in Mono on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'd like to benchmark I/O performance for a hard disk and I'd like to do that in C#. I've done that before in other programming languages and I'm doing that now in C# in the context of some evaluation of API performance in programming languages.

What I am doing is creating a large buffer of 1 MByte filled with random data. I then write the buffer repeatedly to a file using a regular FileStream, creating many GBytes of data in seconds. Strangely whatever I do - if I invoke Flush() during writes, at the end of writes, or even create a write-through-stream - I get results much better than theoretically possible: At least about three times faster than the I/O this disk is capable of doing. The logical conclusion is: I/O still is asynchronous though I invoke Flush() or use the write-through-option during stream creation.

That brings me to the conclusion that Flush() on a FileStream is not implemented in Mono. My question now is: How can I perform unbuffered file I/O  with ensuring that all data is written as expected? Am I missing something or is there some special trick I'm not aware of?

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            byte[] mem = new byte[1024 * 1024];
            Random r = new Random();
            r.NextBytes(mem);

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("/home/myuser/benchmark.tmp", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            DateTime t1 = DateTime.Now;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2048; i++) {
                fs.Write(mem, 0, mem.Length);
                fs.Flush();
            }
            fs.Flush();
            DateTime t2 = DateTime.Now;
            fs.Close();

            double t = (1024.0 * 1024 * 2048) / (t2 - t1).TotalSeconds;
            Console.WriteLine(t + " bytes/s");

            t = t / (1024 * 1024);
            Console.WriteLine(t + " mbytes/s");
        }
    }
}
```

This writes 2 GByte of data.

Output:

```
3000980511.29551 bytes/s
2861.95803765823 mbytes/s
```

The disk is capable of doing about 500 mbyte/s so Flush() seems to have no effect.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can at least see from where you drew your conclusions

Comment: See above......